# Organize files by name into categorical subfolders in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need an algorithm that organize some files in a directory by the name of the file.

I wrote some categories:

```
Bread = ["bread", "pizza", "spaghetti"]
Meat = ["hamburger", "meat", "porkchop"]
```

If a file name is `hamburger recipe.txt`, I need this file to be moved to a particular directory called `Meat`.

If another file name is `bread with vegetables.doc`, this file will be moved to the folder named `Bread`.

I tried to write this, but it doesn't work:

```
meat = ["hamburger", "meat", "porkchop"]

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if meat in filename:
        os.rename(filename, "Meat/" + filename)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Thanks ggorlen! I wrote down "+" in the original code, I was wrong in transcribing. Sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test if [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the food items in your `meat` category appears in the filename:

```
meat = ["hamburger", "meat", "porkchop"]

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if any(food in filename for food in meat):
        os.rename(filename, "Meat/" + filename)
```

Comment: It's working, but how can I mantain the original name of the file?

Comment: I hadn't realised that you had put quotes around `filename`... There shouldn't be any, as you want to use the `filename` variable. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right idea. I'd use a dictionary to make categories easier to manipulate. While it makes sense to map categories to keywords for organizational purposes, lookups will be faster by inverting the dict. At that point, we can split each filename on non-word characters, check our keyword lookup table for a match, create any nonexistent directories and move files as necessary.

```
import os
import re

path = "."
categories = {
    "meat": ["hamburger", "meat", "porkchop"],
    "bread": ["bread", "pizza", "spaghetti"]
} 
keywords = {}

for k, v in categories.items():
    for x in v:
        keywords[x] = k

for filename in [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(x)]:
    for term in [x for x in re.split(r"\W+", filename.lower()) if x in keywords]:
        dest = os.path.join(keywords[term], filename)
        src = os.path.join(path, filename)

        try:
            if not os.path.exists(keywords[term]):
                os.makedirs(keywords[term])

            os.rename(src, dest)
        except (FileNotFoundError, FileExistsError) as e:
            print(e)
```